# Multi file upload issue

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I used [multi file upload](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/) to upload file in ASP.Net without issues. But now i want to add more functionality like creating thumbnails while uploading below is my code:

```
try
        {
            string _path = "~/photos/realimg/";
            string _thumPath = "~/photos/thumbimg/";
            // Get the HttpFileCollection
            HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
            for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
                if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    _path += System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName);
                    _thumPath += System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName.Insert(0, "thumb_"));
                    hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(_path));
                    SavePicPath(_path);
                    System.Drawing.Image realImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(_path));

                    Int32 rH = realImg.Height;
                    Int32 rW = realImg.Width;

                    Int32 fW = 170;
                    Int32 fH = (Int32)Math.Floor((double)rH * (fW / rW));
                    System.Drawing.Image thumbimg = realImg.GetThumbnailImage(fW, fH, null, IntPtr.Zero);

                    thumbimg.Save(Server.MapPath(_thumPath));
                    SavePicPath(_thumPath);

                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
```

Anytime it gets to GetThumbnailImage i get an error "Out of memory" please any correction or what am i doing wrong

Comment: Change int values to (float or double)

Comment: @MMK thanks it worked! but please what is the secret behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change int values to (float or double). i think here `fw/rw` returning int value than float or double value.